# How to apply the Chain rule when using standard integrals/differentials?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

For example, $\frac{d}{dx} \,\arctan x = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and I know this because it is given to me in table of standard derivatives and integrals. But if I want to differentiate something like $\arctan \left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)$, is this the answer?

$$\frac{d}{dx} \,\arctan \left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right) = \frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^2}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)$$

Can I even do this differentiation at all using the standard derivative given to me? And what about for integration? For example, it is given to me that

$$ \int \tan x \,dx = \ln|\sec x| + C$$

However, is the following correct?

$$ \int \tan (2x-3) \,dx = \frac{1}{2}\,\ln\big|\sec (2x-3)\big| + C $$

I would be grateful if someone could explain the above examples and generalise this topic too.

Comment: When integrating, it's call *u-substitution*.

Comment: Please improve your question by using $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 0):

You computation of the differentiation of $arctan(\frac{1-x}{1+x})$ is correct. When differentiating $f(g(x))$ you get $f^{'}(g(x)) g^{'}(x)$. The integral is
\begin{equation}
\int{tan(2x-3)}=-\frac{1}{2} log(cos(3-2x))
\end{equation}